# How to calculate timedifference in one column for a day with a custom start time

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing 160,000 entries. Each entry represents one measurement value at a given time spanning 12 Years; MySQL version is 5.6

```
id  date_obs        value_obs
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1,  2006-01-22T20:21:46    +30),
2,  2006-01-22T22:34:35    +30),
3,  2006-01-22T23:42:37    +30),
4,  2006-01-23T00:42:15    +30),
5,  2006-01-23T00:57:23    +30),
6,  2006-01-23T01:17:13    +30), 
7,  2006-01-23T02:22:32    +30),
8,  2006-01-24T19:26:35    +30),
9,  2006-01-24T20:01:29    +30),
10, 2006-01-24T21:12:02    +10),
11, 2006-01-24T21:12:17    +10),
12, 2006-01-24T21:12:31    +10),
13, 2006-01-28T20:10:43    +30),
14, 2006-01-28T20:22:39    +30),
15, 2006-01-28T21:33:09    +10),
16, 2006-01-28T22:17:17    +10);
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I am searching for the number of seconds between the first and last measurement on each day, grouped by month.

But: one day lasts from 12:00 to 12:00 and NOT vom 00:00 to 24:00

Like id 1-7 belong to one day, id 8-12 to the next day and id 13-16 to the following day.

Expected result is:

```
2006-01-22   = 21646
2006-01-24   = 6356
2006-01-28   = 7594
```

My query is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_obs`, '%Y-%m-%d') as T_DATE,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(`date_obs`),MAX(`date_obs`)) as T_SESSION
FROM t1
GROUP BY LEFT(`date_obs`,10);
```

Of course the result is not correct:

```
 2006-01-22   = 12051
 2006-01-23   = 6017
 2006-01-24   = 6356
 2006-01-28   = 7594
```

because id's 1-3 and 4-7 are treated as measurements from two separate days.
see:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9e570/2/0

Comment: Do you mean ids 1-3 are part of one day, 4-7 of another day, 8-12 and 13-16 ?

Comment: Nope. Like I said: id 1-7 belong to one day, id 8-12 to the next day and id 13-16 to the following day.

Comment: Pls explain why 2006-01-22T20:21:46 (id=1) and 2006-01-23T02:22:32 (id=7) are considered to be in the same day. Do you mean that the day 2006-01-22 ranges from 2006-01-22T12:00:00 to 2006-01-23T12:00:00 ?

Comment: Correct. In fact the measurements are always taken in the nighttime and starting with sunset continuing to the next morning until sunrise.

Comment: @BruceCallahan have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Shift each time of period from noon to next noon into one date by adding 12 hours in group clause

```
SELECT 
   DATE(`date_obs`) as T_DATE, 
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,MIN(`date_obs`),MAX(`date_obs`)) as T_SESSION
FROM t1
GROUP BY date(`date_obs` + INTERVAL 12 HOUR);
```

results in

```
T_DATE      T_SESSION
2006-01-22  21646
2006-01-24  6356
2006-01-28  7594
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9e570/10)

Comment: Thanks, overall that worked. But sometimes I get two groups of the same day with some peculiar results. Must have something to do if there are single isolated days followed by some consecutive days. Still wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Mysql can get any data for each column when group records. Try `DATE_FORMAT(min(`date_obs`), '%Y-%m-%d') as T_DATE, - it will get minimal date. but if one group has entry from midnight to noon and next from noon to midnight of the same day, it will be twice

Comment: Or to get end date of period DATE_FORMAT(`date_obs` + INTERVAL 12 HOURS, '%Y-%m-%d') as T_DATE,

Comment: @BruceCallahan By the way, you can write `date(date_obs + INTERVAL 12 HOUR) as T_DATE` with the same result

Comment: Yea - I guess there's no way around it for this case: (if one group has entry from midnight to noon and next from noon to midnight of the same day, it will be twice ). But the values for both entries are correct.

Comment: Try to shift output date too   `date(date_obs + INTERVAL 12 HOUR) as T_DATE`. But I'm not sure it avoids non-desired date. Value should be correct